# How to use the argument from function for body of http request with Dio package

Tags: flutter, http, dart, mobile, dio

```
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    String url = "https://phone-book-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/signin";
    Response response;
    var dio = Dio();
    response = await dio.post(url,
        data: {"email": email, "password": password);
    print(response.data);
  }
```

if i make function with the above code i got some error, but if i fill the body with hard code, it no error happen, and i can receive the response, below the code example

```
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    String url = "https://phone-book-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/signin";
    Response response;
    var dio = Dio();
    response = await dio.post(url,
        data: {"email": "l200140004@gmail.com", "password": "l200140004");
    print(response.data);
  }
```

anyone can help me and explaine to me about it case, please...

Comment: I hope the hard coded email and password you provided are just an example, and not your actual login information. But to the question, how is the first function's arguments being populated and what error are you seeing?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]

Comment: in this function, i want to post request with Dio, and the value of the body is from the parameter/agument from the function

Comment: the above code just example from what my problem

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry All, my password input is wrong, so it can be error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).